# Extracting paragraph from a document based on Numerals

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, data

I am new to the Data Science. The problem I want to solve is relatively simple in terms of the problem statement.

Given a Numbered document (usually a pdf) with/without an index, I need to extract all the sections based on their numerical value.

For example, a document may have something like this

```
1. Title1
  1.1 Sub Title1
    1.1.1 Sub Sub Title 1
       Lorem Ipsum (a big paragraph)
    1.1.2 Sub Title 2
       Some table and graphs
  1.2 Sub Title 2
2. Title 2
......
```

I think you get the point. What I have given above is a very reduced set of a bigger problem I am trying to solve. Is there any tool or technique that is available out there that can do the extraction by sections out of the box. Meaning when I query for Title1 -- it should give all of the Title1 in a tree format.

If there are no such tools or techniques that exist, can someone point me in the right direction/approach to attack this problem?

Comment: @StephenRauch: how do you say this is straight-forward? is there any tools out there that do this kinda thing? I am sure I am not the first one to be solving this problem.

Comment: @StephenRauch - great! only few hours. can you do it for me? I can pay you

Comment: i mean not on stackexchange ofcourse. Perhaps you can do this as a freelance item. You may connect with me on linkedin and we can take it  from there

Comment: Try Freelancer or Upwork

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file can be converted to "plain text" from pdf format, you could write a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) rule to find the start of sections.

It would require finding all lines that start with a digit followed by a literal period, ignoring tabs. The regular expression is something like `(^\t*\d\.)`